# How to read/access sentiment analysis results from luis

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

I am using azure bot framework with LUIS. I am able to get the intent, and entity in the backend(node js). Similarly are we able to get sentiment analysis as well?

Here below the LUIS result.

**intents** 
0
intent  "Management Team"
score   0.191086322

**entities**    []

**sentimentAnalysis**
label   "negative"
score   0.20460996

Here below the node code i am using to get  entityt/intent

```
bot.dialog('Team',[
(session, results) => {
  entity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(results.intent.entities, 'Team');
}
```

Similarly is there any way to access sentiment analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, sentiment analysis is not supported in v3 BotFramework (node or C#). However there is currently a PR to add such support for the LUIS feature to the C# SDK that you can track [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/pull/4835).